# How to make android wear Vibrate in an app for phones and tablets?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I have made an interval timer app for phones and tablets. I want to make my watch Vibrate too when the workout starts and stops. Do you need to make full app for wear or can you just get your wear to Vibrate in the existing app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show a notifcation for starting and finishing the workout it will be automatically shown on the wearable as well. You can add vibration to the notification with the `NotificationCompat.Builder setVibrate(long[] pattern)` method.

If you only want to make the wearable vibrate and don't want to show a notification on your phone, your only option is to create a separate app for the wearable.

If your not familiar with developing separate apps for wearables, here you can find all the basic information for it: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html